# Having issues with touchesBegan method

Tags: ios, objective-c, button, sprite-kit, touchesbegan

I have my sound on logo showing up on the screen and the sound off logo appears when i test it. what I want it to do is change from sound on to sound off when I tap on it. The buttons do acknowledge the tap but nothing happens. I don't have much experience in change node images when they're tapped so I don't really know if I used the most efficient code. Can someone look over my code and see what's wrong? Thanks in advance!

```
@implementation MyScene
{
SKSpriteNode *soundLogo;
SKSpriteNode *soundOff;
}

-(void) addSoundOff:(CGSize)size {
soundOff = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"soundOff"];
//resize sprite
soundOff.size = CGSizeMake(soundOff.size.width/2.25, soundOff.size.height/2.25);
//position it
soundOff.position = CGPointMake(65, 25);
//name sound off
soundOff.name = @"soundOff";

soundOff.zPosition = 0;
soundOff.alpha = 0;
//[self addChild:soundOff];
}


-(void) addSoundOn:(CGSize)size {
soundLogo = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"soundLogo"];
//resize sprite
soundLogo.size = CGSizeMake(soundLogo.size.width/2.25, soundLogo.size.height/2.25);
//position sprite
CGPoint myPoint = CGPointMake(65, 25);
soundLogo.position = myPoint;
//name sound logo
soundLogo.name = @"soundOn";
//add action

//soundLogo.alpha = 1;
soundLogo.zPosition = 100;

[self addChild:soundLogo];
}

-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:location];

if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"soundOn"]) {

    soundOff.zPosition = 100;
    soundOff.alpha = 1;
    soundLogo.alpha = 0;
    soundLogo.zPosition = 0;

//        [node removeFromParent];
//        [node addChild:soundOff];
    NSLog(@"sound on is pressed");
 }

if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"soundOff"]) {

    soundLogo.zPosition = 100;
    soundLogo.alpha = 1;
    soundOff.alpha = 0;
    soundOff.zPosition = 0;

//        [node removeFromParent];
//        [node addChild:soundLogo];
    NSLog(@"sound off is pressed");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems nothing wrong in your `addSoundOff` and `addSoundOn` functions. What you can do as one of the solutions to change `alpha` and `zPosition` properties of `SKSpriteNode` . And also create`soundOff` and `soundLogo` as instance variables under the implementation. So here is the all code:

```
#import "MyScene.h"

@implementation MyScene
{
    SKSpriteNode *soundLogo;
    SKSpriteNode *soundOff;
}

-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {    
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
        /* Setup your scene here */

        self.backgroundColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:0.15 green:0.15 blue:0.3 alpha:1.0];

        [self addSoundOn:self.size];
        [self addSoundOff:self.size];

    }
    return self;
}

-(void) addSoundOff:(CGSize)size {
    soundOff = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"soundOff"];
    //resize sprite
    soundOff.size = CGSizeMake(soundOff.size.width/2.25, soundOff.size.height/2.25);
    //position it
    soundOff.position = CGPointMake(65, 25);
    //name sound off
    soundOff.name = @"soundOff";

    soundOff.alpha = 0;
    soundOff.zPosition = 0;
    [self addChild:soundOff];

}

-(void) addSoundOn:(CGSize)size {
    SKTexture *soundOn = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"soundLogo"];
    soundLogo = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:soundOn];
    //resize sprite
    soundLogo.size = CGSizeMake(soundLogo.size.width/2.25, soundLogo.size.height/2.25);
    //position sprite
    CGPoint myPoint = CGPointMake(65, 25);
    soundLogo.position = myPoint;
    //name sound logo
    soundLogo.name = @"soundOn";
    //add action

    soundLogo.zPosition = 100;
    [self addChild:soundLogo];
}

-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
    SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:location];

    //sound logo pressed to turn sound on/off
    if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"soundOn"]) {

        soundOff.alpha = 1;
        soundOff.zPosition = 100;
        soundLogo.alpha = 0;
        soundLogo.zPosition = 0;

        NSLog(@"sound on is pressed");
    }

    if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"soundOff"]) {

        soundOff.alpha = 0;
        soundOff.zPosition = 0;
        soundLogo.alpha = 1;
        soundLogo.zPosition = 100;
        NSLog(@"sound off is pressed");
    }
}


@end
```

Comment: Ok thought that would work but when I run it, it shows the soundOn button so I click it and it says that I'm tapping on the soundOff button and nothing happens.

Comment: So the problem is that when I start it the soundOff button is above the soundOn but it's invisible. So all I see is the soundOn button, when I try to tap the soundOn button it really is just hitting the soundOff button and not giving it a chance to run the touchesBegan method properly.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I changed the answer, hope it works as you wish now. @NicholasWhitley

Comment: hmm I could've swore that would work to but when I run it and tap the sound button, it disappears and when i keep tapping it only reacts to the sound on. the sound off is also not popping up.

Comment: I edited my message, and put all the code inside. I tested it on iPhone 5 and it was doing ok. Can you retry now, and let me know if it works or not. @NicholasWhitley

Comment: Ok still having that same issue. I edited my code that I'm using back in the question. I don't see what I'm doing differently. @AhmetCevdet

Comment: Hmmm I looked at your code, [self addChild:soundOff]; shouldn't be in comment, and the rest seems ok. @NicholasWhitley